# Vaadin table column order is getting changed automatically

Tags: vaadin8

I have created a table which has few columns in it. i have given header names for each column. After table initialization i see that column are not appearing in the order in which they are added in table. Column names are reordered alphabetically. Please find below the code of the same.

```
private Table createGridTable() {
    Table grid = new FilterAndPagedTable(this.generateTableOptions());
    grid.addContainerProperty("previousPeriod", String.class, null);
    grid.addContainerProperty("prevchannelA", Float.class, null);
    grid.addContainerProperty("prevchannelB", Float.class, null);
    grid.addContainerProperty("prevchannelC", Float.class, null);
    grid.addContainerProperty("prevchannelD", Float.class, null);
    grid.addContainerProperty("prevAllChannelCons", Float.class, null);
    grid.addContainerProperty("presentPeriod", String.class, null);
    grid.addContainerProperty("presentchannelA", Float.class, null);
    grid.addContainerProperty("presentchannelB", Float.class, null);
    grid.addContainerProperty("presentchannelC", Float.class, null);
    grid.addContainerProperty("presentchannelD", Float.class, null);
    grid.addContainerProperty("presentAllChannelCons", Float.class, null);
    grid.addContainerProperty("diffOfPrevNPresent", Float.class, null);
    grid.addContainerProperty("percentageChangeOfPrevNPresent", String.class, null);

    grid.setColumnHeader("previousPeriod", PrevYearConstants.PREVIOUS_PERIOD);
    grid.setColumnHeader("prevchannelA", IemsConstants.A_DC_Power);
    grid.setColumnHeader("prevchannelB", IemsConstants.B_Essential_Cooling);
    grid.setColumnHeader("prevchannelC", IemsConstants.C_UPS_Power);
    grid.setColumnHeader("prevchannelD", IemsConstants.D_Non_Essential_Cooling);
    grid.setColumnHeader("prevAllChannelCons", "A + B + C + D");
    grid.setColumnHeader("presentPeriod", PrevYearConstants.PRESENT_PERIOD);
    grid.setColumnHeader("presentchannelA", IemsConstants.A_DC_Power);
    grid.setColumnHeader("presentchannelB", IemsConstants.B_Essential_Cooling);
    grid.setColumnHeader("presentchannelC", IemsConstants.C_UPS_Power);
    grid.setColumnHeader("presentchannelD", IemsConstants.D_Non_Essential_Cooling);
    grid.setColumnHeader("presentAllChannelCons", "A + B + C + D");
    grid.setColumnHeader("diffOfPrevNPresent", PrevYearConstants.DIFFERENCE);
    grid.setColumnHeader("percentageChangeOfPrevNPresent", PrevYearConstants.PERCENTAGE);
    System.out.println(grid.isSortAscending());
    System.out.println(grid.isSortEnabled());
    grid.setVisibleColumns(new Object[] { "previousPeriod", "prevchannelA", "prevchannelB", "prevchannelC",
            "prevchannelD", "prevAllChannelCons", "presentPeriod", "presentchannelA", "presentchannelB",
            "presentchannelC", "presentchannelD", "presentAllChannelCons", "diffOfPrevNPresent",
            "percentageChangeOfPrevNPresent" });



    grid.setSizeFull();
    return grid;
}

public FilterAndPagedTableOptions generateTableOptions() {
    FilterAndPagedTableOptions fptOptions = new FilterAndPagedTableOptions();
    fptOptions.setCollapseAllowed(false);
    fptOptions.setColumnReorderingAllowed(false);
    fptOptions.setSortAllowed(false);
    fptOptions.setShowInbuiltFilterBar(false);
    return fptOptions;
}
```

i am loading data in table as below

```
List<PrevYearConsumption> tableContainer = viewElements.get(PrevYearConstants.PREV_YEAR_TABLE_CONFIG)
                    .getTableContainer();
            this.grid.setPageLength(tableContainer.size());
            BeanItemContainer container = new BeanItemContainer<PrevYearConsumption>(PrevYearConsumption.class);
            container.addAll(tableContainer);
            this.grid.setContainerDataSource(container);
```

The order of columns in table is not coming the way i have added in table's header. It is coming in random manner.
I am using vaadin 8.

Kindly help here .
Let me know in case any further info is required.

Comment: Is the column order the same as in setVisibleColumns(..)? That is the method which sets the ordering.

Comment: @TatuLund  yes the order of fields in bean class , order of header column and the visible columns all are same.

Answer (score 0):

Is this pure Vaadin 8 or is it Vaadin 7 or is it Vaadin 8 with compatibility packages?

i would try to invoke

```
grid.setVisibleColumns(new Object[] { "previousPeriod", "prevchannelA", "prevchannelB", "prevchannelC",
        "prevchannelD", "prevAllChannelCons", "presentPeriod", "presentchannelA", "presentchannelB",
        "presentchannelC", "presentchannelD", "presentAllChannelCons", "diffOfPrevNPresent",
        "percentageChangeOfPrevNPresent" });
```

after loading the data in the table.